# How to use distinct query in Realm Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm

I am looking for a way to select only distinct values from my Realm database. In java, unique values are returned like this -

```
RealmResults<Person> unique = realm.where(Person.class).distinct("name");
```

But, I am not able to find a way to do the same in Realm Xamarin(.net).

Answer (score 1):

Realm for .Net does not directly support Linq's `Distinct`.

> Set Operators
>
> Distinct, Union, Intersect, and Except are not supported.

re: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/linqsupport.html

You can take the `IRealmCollection` to a list (`ToList`) and then perform a Linq Distinct on the result.

Assuming this model:

```
public class ARealmClass : RealmObject
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string KeyString { get; set; }
}
```

You need an `IEqualityComparer`. This is a quick example that compares a single property `KeyString` of `ARealmClass`:

```
public class ARealmClassKeyStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<ARealmClass>
{
    public bool Equals(ARealmClass x, ARealmClass y)
    {
        return (x.KeyString == y.KeyString);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ARealmClass obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then your Realm and Linq query:

```
var queryResults = realm.All<ARealmClass>().ToList().Distinct(new ARealmClassKeyStringComparer());
```

The downside is this materializes the entire collection of `ARealmClass` objects in order to take them to a list and perform the distinct operation. If possible `Where` filter  the `All<ARealmClass>()` to a subset before applying  `ToList`.

Answer (score 0):

This is real question with Linq query support distinct or not....

In standar Linq Query its not support but you can use some additional components to get support of it > [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

and if your try to write your won query its not much difficult

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}


var query = people.DistinctBy(p => p.Id);
```

Hope this is what your expected